# Primefaces submit form on p:tabView tab change

Tags: forms, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, tabview

I have a huge JSF application created using primefaces version 6.0 running on WebSphere Application Server, Version 8.5.5. I want to avoid nested forms so my `p:tabView` is not included in a form but each tab has its own form. Source for my tab view looks something like this:

```
      <p:tabView activeIndex="#{tabViewBean.selectedTab}" id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="false" widgetVar="tabViewWidget">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{tabViewBean.handleTabChange}" update=":tabView" />
        <p:tab id="tab1" title="First tab">
            <h:form id="FirstTabForm">
                <ui:include src="/views/test/firstTabTab.xhtml"/>
            </h:form>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="tab2" title="Drugi tab">
            <h:form id="SecondTabForm">
                <ui:include src="/views/test/secondTab.xhtml"/>
            </h:form>
        </p:tab>

      ... more tabs ...

    </p:tabView>
```

Is there a way I can submit the form inside current tab without clicking commandButton inside it. I would like to achieve that on tab change event.

Each tab has 15-20 input fields and I don't want to use ajax on each value change because it is slowing down my application significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `process`attribute with a dynamic selector on `tabChange` event.

You can see it in action here: [Ajax Framework - Partial Process](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/process.xhtml)